# Understanding of CPU units in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to understand meaning of vCPU and CPU units and connection of these concepts to physical CPU. 
I have ECS cluster with one cluster instance, which is m5ad.large EC2 instance.
Here is output of `lscpu` command on this instance:

```
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               1
Model name:          AMD EPYC 7571
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             2892.092
BogoMIPS:            4399.83
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cmp_legacy cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch topoext vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 clzero xsaveerptr arat npt nrip_save
```

This instance has one processor (`Socket(s): 1`), one core per socket and 2 threads per core, that's why actual number of threads is `number of sockets * number of cores per socket * number of threads per core = 1 * 1 * 2 = 2`. 
So, if I understand correct, this value is also a number of available vCPU, and vCPU is kernel thread. 
As it said in ECS documentation, number of CPU units can be calculated as `number of vCPU * 1024`. In this case, there are 2048 CPU units 
My questions are what is CPU unit, why am I need to multiply on 1024 and what is physical connection between processor and CPU units?

Answer (score 24):

When running containers, CPU allocation is typically done using CPU units as described in the ECS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#task_size

1024 CPU units corresponds to 1 vCPU.

In the task definition you can specify the CPU allocation using either CPU units (e.g. 1024) or as a vCPU string (e.g. 1 vCPU).

You don't **have to** convert to CPU units, ECS can do that for you. If you prefer to think of CPU allocation using vCPUs, that's fully supported.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. So, if I understand correct, if I allocate 1 vCPU for container, there will be one kernel thread reserved for this container. But how much CPU resources will be allocated, if I specify 512 CPU units (0.5 vCPU)? Will this influence on how much time this container can use thread?

Comment: This setting is similar to the --cpu-shares setting used by Docker and you can find more information in the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu. If you set this to 0.5 vCPU (or 512), your task will get at most 50% of a CPU core every second.

Comment: Oh, I see. Great! Thank's a lot, @Mats Lannér. It's the very information I needed